# Illustrator/Photoshop/Flash/InDesign Purchase

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, adobe-flash

I used to work in graphic design years ago, however no longer a design pro, but am considering buying a license for Illustrator/Photoshop/Flash/InDesign just to have.

Does anyone have any recommendations of what I should look for?

Was thinking of buying something off Ebay?

Comment: I'm not sure you can even by a license anymore. You sort of "rent" Adobe's products on a monthly basis. Check out their webpage.

Comment: You **can't** "buy" a license for anything after CS6 and finding legacy versions may be difficult. And legacy versions generally run poorly on more modern operating systems. The *best* you could possible do is to find a copy of CS6 for sale somewhere (Adobe doesn't sell it). That's the *last* release which offered a perpetual license purchase. Note that unless the legacy software comes with a *legitimate* **Transfer of Ownership** form from Adobe, it is pirated software. Adobe learned they can pillage their customers more by leasing software rather than selling it.

Comment: @Scott. I'd upvote that. Please don't answer in the comments. Thanks.

Comment: @Vincent only kind of answered because I voted to close since this really isn't a *design* question. But I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today Adobe only rents its professional "Creative Cloud" stuff. You install the programs normally, but they die as soon as you do not pay the rent. The software needs regular "payments ok" acknowledgements via the internet or they do not run.

There are several different licensing schemes available, but perpetual (pay once) isn't one of them.

In theory you can find in Ebay or other marketplaces Adobe pro software packages from the era before Creative Cloud. They have some drawbacks:

- you cannot be sure are the given keys valid
- you can get a crack with a bunch of malware
- if someone sells his used old packages, the purchase must be accepted by Adobe. Otherwise the right to use doesn't get transferred.
- the prices are higher than they were when the packages were new
- nobody quarantees the compatibility with newest Win or MacOS.

Thus I cannot recommend Ebay purchases. I have bought my ancient package "face to face" and all went smoothly.

If you can't afford Adobe pro stuff for hobby purposes, goto freeware or take something less pricey commercial software. Search for alternatives. PS, Illustrator and InD seem to have them at least to some degree. I do not know Flash well enough. Check this: http://www.animationinsider.com/2015/01/software-vectorian-giotto-an-actual-flash-alternative/